# react-bootstrap/Image don't load imgURL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

```
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
...
<Image src={user && user.photoURL}
                    style={{ width: '30p', height: '30px', marginTop: '3px' }}
                    roundedCircle />
```

this code doesn't work...

I expact this URL is "http:gravatar.com/avatar/131027761e6030617f244ed2031ab496?d=identicon"
but that URL is "http://localhost:3000/gravatar.com/avatar/131027761e6030617f244ed2031ab496?d=identicon"

Answer (score 0):

I found answer that,
Because it's url is http:

you have to write url http:// or https://

*^^*

Answer (score 0):

use require in src property

```
<Image src={require(user && user.photoURL)}
                    style={{ width: '30p', height: '30px', marginTop: '3px' }}
                    roundedCircle />
```